# How to get systemlogs in bitnami wordpress bitnami in Aws

Tags: wordpress, bitnami

I have created an instance using WordPress Bitnami.  I have followed the instructions to find my password in the System Log but the menu has been updated and does not give me the option to "Get System Log" in "Instance Settings" Could you help me.  I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here.

You can get the system's log information by clicking on "Monitor & troubleshoot > Get system log"

[image]

You can also obtain the app's password using a SSH connection. Once you are inside the machine, you can run this command to obtain it

```
cat /home/bitnami/bitnami_credentials
```

More info [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/get-started/find-credentials/#option-2-find-credentials-by-connecting-to-your-application-through-ssh)